# Regex to get images on page including src-set and data-src varients

Tags: php, regex

I want to get the full path/url of all images contained in a HTML page. 
including src-set and all the types of data-src variants people may use.

matching anything on the page that is a ../image.jpg or http://domain.ca/some/path/image.jpg is what I am looking for.

Trying to use this regex for preg_match_all

```
/(https?:\/\/|\/|\/|^((?:\.\.\/)+))[^\/\s]+\/\S+\.(jpg|png|gif)/
```

https://regex101.com/r/69F1zL/3

Here are the types of images I may come across

```
../yep.jpg
yep.jpg
im/some.jpg
/some.jpg
src="../uploads/2016/02/logo-home.png" 
im/sfds/some.jpg
url(thedir/img.jpg)
../../yep.jpg

src="https://www.thesite.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/logo-home.png" 
data-huge="some/big.jpg" 
src="https://www.thesite.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/logo-home.png"
srcset="https://www.thesite.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/logo-home.png 793w,
https://www.thesite.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/logo-home-300x201.png 300w,
https://www.thesite.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/logo-home-768x514.png 768w,
https://www.thesite.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/logo-home-700x469.png 700w"
sizes="(max-width: 793px) 100vw, 793px" /></div>
```

https://regex101.com/r/69F1zL/3
[image: https://regex101.com/r/69F1zL/3]

Comment: Please downvote with a reason so that I can learn to not commit the same sins again.

Comment: mp4 = image? Question is not clear: do you want just all image-names or all urls to `<img>`?

Comment: Thanks, want to get the full url of image as in the source, so http://dom.com/image.jpg or ../../image.jpg and updated it to be more clear hopefully

Comment: then why use a regex with `https...` and not something like `src...`?

Comment: that's probably the downvote, your are not clearly stating your expected output (the real input would probable help as well)

Comment: not every type of image will have a src

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly

maybe something very generic like

```
[^"'=\s]+\.(jpe?g|png|gif)
```

See https://regex101.com/r/69F1zL/4

Comment: Thats perfect man thanks, will look at the explanations on the regex101 site to learn about it